# What machine learning model to choose?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, bigdata

I have a table in .csv format that includes the following columns:

```
recipe, defect, material1, material2, material3, ..., material122
```

1. *recipe* is an ID of a combination of one or more materials (for example, *recipe_1* corresponds to *material1 + material3 + material28* while *recipe_2* corresponds to *material3 + material5*).
2. *defect* is an ID that represents a defect found in some product that was made using some *recipe*.
3. *materialN* is a weight of some material. However, I use a ratio of materials instead of their weights (for example, I say that *material1 = 0.25* and *material2 = 0.75* instead of saying that *material1 = 5 kg* and *material2 = 15 kg* for a given *recipe = material1 + material2*).

Note: there can be more than one defect for the same recipe.

[This is how my train table looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DzEG.png) It includes 124 columns and almost 90.000 rows.

Now, I need to train some model using *material1, material2, material3, ..., material122* as input and *defect* as output. For example, let's take rows 2-15 from my file:

```
given input: [0, 0, 0.898, 0.062, 0.039, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0] // ratios of materials for recipe 1701192
given output: [149, 146, 148, 90, 89, ..., 59, 71, 63] // defects found for recipe 1701192
```

The main problem I see here is that the same *recipe* corresponds to different *defects*. Moreover, I need to predict multiple *defects* in a test dataset given in another file.

[This is how the test dataset looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwhZM.png) It includes 123 columns and just 8400 rows. Note that there is no information about *defects* - I need to predict them.

Unfortunately, I'm not aware of models which allow multiple predictions for some combination of properties. Could you recommend anything? It can be a neural network as well.

Answer (score 0):

One way this can be done is doing Multivariate Regression. If you know all the types(categories) of defect that will occur, then you can take them as 'n' dependent variable and then perform regression on your data.
One thing you should before running regression is standardizing or normalizing your input data (if you haven't done it already). If all your output variable are independent of each other then you can also run separate analysis for each of them in your model.